# C# Nunit Moq Cannot make test pass

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, ncrunch

I have this class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private ISomeInterface blabla;

    public MyClass() : this(new SomeInterfaceImplementation()) {}

    internal MyClass(ISomeInterface blabla)
    {
        this.blabla = blabla;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(string id, int value1, int value2)
    {
        this.blabla.DoSomethingWith(id, new ValueClass(value1, value2))
    }
}
```

I also have this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTest
{
    private const string ID = "id";
    private const int VALUE1 = 1;
    private const int VALUE2 = 2;

    private ValueClass valueClass;

    private Mock<ISomeInterface> mockInterface;

    private MyClass myClass;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.valueClass = new ValueClass(VALUE1, VALUE2);
        this.mockInterface = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
        this.myClass = new MyClass(this.mockInterface.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GIVEN_AnID_AND_AValue1_AND_AValue2_WHEN_DoingSomeMethod_THEN_TheSomeInterfaceShouldDoSomething()
    {
        this.myClass.SomeMethod(ID, VALUE1, VALUE2);
        this.mockInterface.Verify(m => m.DoSomethingWith(ID, this.valueClass), Times.Once()); //<- Test fails here!
    }
}
```

I don't know why but I can't get this test to pass. NCrunch is giving me the following error message:

> Moq.MockException :  Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0
>   times: m => m.DoSomethingWith("ID", .valueClass) No setups
>   configured.
>
> Performed invocations:
>
> ISomeInterface.DoSomethingWith("ID",
>   MyNamespace.ValueClass)    at
>   Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1
>   setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times,
>   Int32 callCount)    at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor
>   targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times
>   times)    at Moq.Mock.Verify[T](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression,
>   Times times, String failMessage)    at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1
>   expression, Times times)    at
>   Tests.MyClassTest.GIVEN_AnID_AND_AValue1_AND_AValue2_WHEN_DoingSomeMethod_THEN_TheSomeInterfaceShouldDoSomething()
>   in
>   C:\MySourceCode\File and line number here.

As you can see, it seems like Moq is "not seeing" my invocation, probably because of the `new ValueClass(value1, value2)` how can I make this test pass or how can I change my design so it is easier to test? Where should I put the `new ValueClass(value1, value2)`?

**EDIT:**

Is this a question I should ask on Software Engineering instead of StackOverflow? Is this out of scope?

Comment: It is trying to compare different value class that in method under test. use `It.Any<ValueClass>()`. you could also apply a predicate if you want to compare the fields/properties if they are exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not matching argument in method call:  `this.valueClass` by default is not equal to `new ValueClass(value1, value2)` because it will be two different instances of `ValueClass`. And by default two instances will be compared by references, which are different. You can:

- Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `ValueClass` to change the way how two instances compared. I.e. compare by values instead of comparing by references.
- Ignore this argument with `It.Any<ValueClass>()`. It's good if you don't care about specific values of `ValueClass` and just want to check method was called. Not always best option
- Use predicate to check values of `ValueClass` manually: `It.Is<ValueClass>(vc => vc.Value1 == VALUE1 && vc.Value2 == VALUE2)`. Sometimes it's also good. E.g. if you cannot override `Equals`. But it makes tests much less readable.

Comment: I just overrode (override, overriden?) the Equals() and GetHashCode() for ValueClass. Test is now passing! Thanks!

Comment: Didn't know you could add predicate! I guess I will use the predicates instead because I'll have to add tests for the Equals() and I would rather not have to.

Comment: @Sebastien you can, but keep in mind redability of your tests. They can become very cluttered. Also imagine - you have 50 tests which check values in predicate. And then you add new field to ValueClass. With Equals you just change overload. With predicate you have to update 50 tests.

Comment: Ooohhh... derpyderp! Equals it is XD! I don't want to break my test every time the ValueClass changes!